# Which frameworks for Python web application?

Tags: web-apps, python, gui, framework, electron

I have some Python script and want to visualize what’s happening using a GUI. It should be cross-platform.

I know there are a lot of different Python GUI interfaces (like PyQT) that are also cross platform. But because of the increasing number of web apps I thought it would be interesting to try this out as well. That would also make it way easier to publish the project as a “real” web project (actually on a website, not just browser powered in the background), as I could just reuse the code from the web app.

As y’all probably noticed I’m new to all of this, so I don’t know how to build the web app. I found electron.js as a framework for running the web app locally like a native app.

Now I still need to build the web app itself. Again there are a lot of different frameworks (React, Flutter...) or I could just use standard HTML/CSS/JS.

After that I still need to find a way to integrate my Python project, so I’ll probably need another framework (Flask, Django...).

That are a lot of new frameworks I’ve never worked with before, so I don’t really know where to start.

My question is: If you were going to build a web app with Python code / backend, how would you structure it? Which frameworks would you use (and why)?

Comment: Not a full answer but I did something similar last years and followed this approach (FastAPI with Vuejs frontend in Tyoescript): https://github.com/cbhagl/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/tree/refactor-frontend